# FTPS download using command line or vb / vba?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, ftps

I've tried everything I can think of  - winscp, aria2c, psftp, windows ftp client, etc., and I can't quite get this.

Amazingly, this is all I need to do:

Download these 2 files (i have the username and password) - it is FTPS protocol.

ftp://hostname.com/Folder/filename.txt

and

ftp://hostname.com/Folder/Filename.csv

That's ALL I need to do ... Any ideas how I can do this through VB / VBA / VBscript?  I've tried 39 different clients, none really worked, or should I say they all require expert level server knowledge.  I just don't have that, but I can follow directions.

Does anyone know what kind of batch file commands would automate Firefox, INternet explorer, or some other gizmo to download these files!

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?

Have you tried writing it with // like ftp://hostname.com//Folder/filename.txt

Comment: Just communicating with the server.  either the command prompt just disappears, the server doesnt' like the port, or the server doesn't like the IP - man I've tried active, passive, until my head is spinning.  My question is how to use some kind of vba or vb script to download the file?  I understand how to write it in, for example, a firefox address window - in fact firefox prompts me for my password and the file comes right up (the text file). the csv prmopts do you want to save or download?  I just need to figure out how to automate!

Comment: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation Have you tried something like this? Instead of put, you use get of course.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but can't figure out the correct syntax for a batch file actually.  That's what I need help with..

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your problem. The syntax from calling a WINSCP script from within a batch file is explained as well as the syntax for the Winscp script in this article.

Comment: I have to admit it doesn't seem like you've worked much with FTPS, FTP and SFTP if you don't understand the thousand-and-1 nuances of working with FTP servers.There are 100 different scenarios in terms of how the server and client communicate; some clients handle this automatically but most do not.  PSFTP.exe, for example, automatically handles just about everything you could imagine as how the server might respond. Many other clients do not, however, and you're left to experiment, unless you're a server expert. winscp syntax examples are only the basic ones, and mostly JS files.

Comment: That is correct. I have nit been using WinScp since I wrote our inhouse SFTP client to integrate into our reporting protocols. But I remember it being just that plain simple. But maybe again I dint understand your problem. The oage clearly describes what to do and otherwise the manual does. 
Passing a script file to a command should not be too brainy if you kniw all about SFTP and I dont have acess to terminals woth winscp these weeks. So enjoy your rudimentary style of rudeness.